# Eclipse proposing me Webapp folder only, rather than webContent folder when creating an new project

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee-6, webapp2, web-content

I am a new learner of Java and JEE technology.

When I create a new web project, Eclipse proposes to me only the `webapp` folder rather than the `webContent` one, when creating a new dynamic web project.

Can somebody help to fix that, I want it to show the appropriate folder, that's to say `webContent` folder, to record the project on it.

The Webcontent folder isn't shown at all on the project explorer, nor proposed to put the project on it, when creating a new project.

[image: png]

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you should check what type of eclipse you are using, for dynamic web project download Eclipse Enterprise.
   If you are not use enterprise version then follow below step.
   To download:-
   (a) visit : https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/
   (b) click on : Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers
2. Secondly, you are using enterprise version of eclipse. There is nothing to worry.
   It's a latest updated version, where webContent is similiar as webapp.
   create your html, jsp, css, javascript file in webapp folder.